# Datepickers in mobile app - Is OK required?

Tags: material-design, datetimepicker, datepicker

I'm going to design a datepicker popup (for a single date). It is going to be like typical calendars, appearing in a box, grouping weeks in rows. Lowest offers are going to be displayed under each day.

So I'm wondering, is it a good idea to place a OK button, and make the date selection a two step task (selecting a day and then pressing OK) or just accepting the date on tapping the day?

At first the one tap alternative seems to be better because of requiring less movements, but in material design and typical controls in iOS, the date picking is a two step task, so I suspect that there must be some rational behind this that I cannot see.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: What if a user miss-clicks a date? It's more annoying having to reopen it and choosing again than just pressing ok. Also, the user can change his mind while selecting, and choose another option.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a bit philosophical. People that don't make many mistakes may hate it because it slows them down, but error-prone folks may appreciate it.

Here's how to decide: would a mistake have (serious) negative repercussions? If not, don't do it.

However, if a mistake deletes a user from a database or something else that is bad, then it would be good to validate it.

Here's a real life use case:  wellsfargo.com has decided that when you log off it will prompt you to confirm that you really want to do that. Why would I scroll my mouse up to the top of the page, locate the log off button and click it if that's not what I wanted to do??  Same for mobile...  very annoying.